# Trocar porta de aplicação web com o Kotlin no Intelij

Tags: java, http, kotlin, jboss, intellij-idea

Estou usando o Kotlin no Intelij junto com o Vertex e o Jboss.

Eu quero trocar a porta padrão da minha aplicação.

Já tentei colocar no VM Options das configurations do run do Inteli uma porta diferente, e já tentei por no gradle.properties o "server.port", mas ele só sobe na 8080

Comment: Bem vindo ao SO-pt, por favor leia o [manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/13561), principalmente a seção [postar código como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/13561). Clique no link editar e coloque o código/erro como texto.

Comment: Darei uma olhada, valeu!